# How to use Spring Social in RESTful webservices created using Jersey

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, jersey-2.0

We have a *restful webservice* (**Jersey and Spring-Boot**). I want to add **spring-social** component in my application, where user will be able to authenticate using **Facebook**. But I am struggling with implementing this.

In our application front-end is *HTML5-Angular JS* and service is *Jersey WS*.

Can someone kindly help me with some reference link(s)/code snippet.

Regards
Anuj

Answer (score 0):

You can check-out [Spring Social Showcase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase) on Github provided by Spring itself.

Comment: Hi Chetan, thanks for your reply. Sample solution provided by Spring is a mix of XML and annotation configuration. I am looking for a solution which is purely annotation based.

Answer (score 0):

Found the below link useful for spring-social implementation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/